# Trouble using AWS Appsync Subscriptions with Node JS and EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, aws-appsync

This is my first question here, and I just started writing Node JS code recently. Right now I am using NodeJS and EJS as a templating engine for my app. My database is DynamoDB and I wanted to make one the tables Realtime by using AWS Appsync. Using Appsync, I can query and mutate the fields in my table but I cannot seem to subscribe to any mutations. No MQTT websockets are open as well when I call my subscribe.

I tried to follow the example for Appsync subscribe on the Appsync documentation but it does not seem to work.

Note: I have defined my infoID variable already, the type information{} is created in the schema and the mutate and query both work. Its just that the subscription doesn't work and no MQTT websocket is created on the template (is this even possible using NodeJS and EJS?).

My schema is as follows:

```js
type Mutation {
 deleteInfo(infoID: String!): information
}

type Subscription {
 onDeleteInfo(infoID: String): information
  @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["deleteInfo"])
}
```

and the code I used to query and subscribe is like this:

```js
const query = gql(`
  query($infoID: String!){
          getInformation(infoID: $infoID) {
            infoID
            noOfDays
            noOfItems
            infoName
   }
           
  }`);

  // Set up a subscription query
  const subquery = gql(`
  subscription ($infoID: String) {
  onDeleteInfo(infoID: $infoID) {
    infoID
    noOfDays
    noOfItems
    infoName
  }
  }`);

  const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
    url: url,
    region: region,
    auth: {
        type: type,
        credentials: credentials,
    }
});

client.hydrated().then(function (client) {
    //Now run a query
    client.query({ query: query, variables: {infoID : infoID} })
        .then(function logData(data) {
            console.log('results of query: ', data);
            var responseData = data;
            res.send(responseData);
        })
        .catch(console.error);

    //Now subscribe to results
    const realtimeResults = function realtimeResults(data) {
            console.log('realtime data: ', data);
            console.log('subcribe is called');
        };

    const observable = client.subscribe({
              query: subquery,
              variables: {infoID : infoID} });

    observable.subscribe({
              next: realtimeResults,
              complete: console.log,
              error: console.log
          });
 };
```

and my mutation code is:

```js
const mutation = gql(`
    mutation($infoID: String!){
            deleteInfo(infoID: $infoID) {
              infoID
              noOfDays
              noOfItems
              infoName
             }
    }`);

  const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
    url: url,
    region: region,
    auth: {
        type: type,
        credentials: credentials,
    }
  });

  client.hydrated().then(function (client) {
      //Now run a query
      client.mutate({ mutation: mutation, variables:{infoID: infoID} })
          .then(function logData(data) {
              console.log('results of mutate: ', data);
          })
          .catch(console.error);
  });
```

Thanks to anyone who answers or read or helps in any way!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share any error messages you are seeing. Also are you running this from a server-side environment and using EJS to server-side render HTML pages that are being sent to the client? This will be an interesting setup because you will need to write your own bi-directional transport layer (or use something like long-polling) that allows newly evaluated EJS templates to be pushed to the client whenever a new subscription result comes through.

Comment: Did you get the chance to look for any error messages. I don't see any use of EJS in your code snippets. Have you tried running the subscription query in the AppSync console to verify that it's a client issue?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are successfully connected to AppSync if you can make mutations and queries from your app. To Debug the subscription problem, you will need to look at the network response for the request. The service will send an error message if something is incorrectly setup.

One common thing to check for is whether the `subscription` is defined in your schema.

```
schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
    subscription: Subscription
}
```

If this is the case, the error message you would receive when making the subscription request is: `Schema is not configured for subscriptions.`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code snippet how to call subscription:

```js
// Set up a subscription query
const subquery = gql`
 subscription onAccept {
  onUpdateDeveloperJob(developerId: "ce261427-84ad-450b-91d1-83b78532dfe6") {
   id
   jobId
   developerId
   selected
  }
 }
`;

// Set up Apollo client
const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
 url,
 region,
 auth: {
  type,
  apiKey
 }
});

client
 .hydrated()
 .then(appsyncClient => {
  // Now run a query
  // appsyncClient
  //  .query({ query })
  //  .then(data => {
  //   console.log('results of query: ', data);
  //  })
  //  .catch(console.error);

  // Now subscribe to results
  const observable = appsyncClient.subscribe({ query: subquery });
  const realtimeResults = function realtimeResults(data) {
   console.log('realtime data: ', data);
  };
  observable.subscribe({
   next: realtimeResults,
   complete: console.log,
   error: console.log
  });
 })
 .catch(console.error);
```

Hope this will be helpful for you.